# Создание Меню на Android

Tags: android, java

Создаю Меню на Андроид. Вроде бы все понятно.
Обработчик при вобре меню описывается в методе `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`.

Так вот. Хотел узнать, MenuItem и item - это зарезервированные слова? Или можно использовать другие?

Comment: >`onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

`MenuItem` - имя класса. Не подлежит изменению.
`item` - произвольное имя входящего параметра метода.

Comment: Спасибо! Все понятно!

Answer (score 3):

`MenuItem` - это название класса, кои передается перегружаемой вами функцией, его изменять нельзя. а уже название объекта - `item` - вы вольны выбирать и распоряжаться им сами